# How to make responsive video container div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make video container div responsive but couldn't manage it so far.

My current CSS for video and container:

```
   .header-container{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
} 

    video-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

     .video{
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
     opacity: 0.78;
     widows: 100%;
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
```

HTML:

```
      <div class="header-container">
 <div class="video-container">
    <video preload ="true" autoplay loop = "loop" volume = "0" style="width: 100%;
    height: auto;">
         <source src = "webd.mp4" type = "video/mp4" >
         </video>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Current look:
[Current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/500db.jpg)

Could you please tell me how can I fix it? I'm still new in HTML and CSS and I really need your help & advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mlegg10/fsftz8rt

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexible-container iframe,
.flexible-container object,
.flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="<source src = "webd.mp4" type = "video/mp4" >" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

a large deal of your code does not associate itself between html and css so it would be helpful to you to understand how it works. Firstly, video is not styled due to it being referenced as .video in your css and your video container has the opposite with the reference being video-container with no dot so your css should look like this

```
.header-container {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.78;
  widows: 100%;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To make a view response you need to scale with its parent and to have most things with % to do this you need to add

```
position: relative;
```

to **all** the parents

After this you need to remove the position absolute as it will mess up your styling by making it an object that does not scale properly

Here is an example of what I think you mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/afut7y99/

Change the sliders at the sides to see how it resizes.

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you for the fast response. I did deleted the dot from video, that was a silly mistake, and I've add position relative to header-container and video-container and removed the position absolute. It looks better now but there is still huge amount of white space. I do understand what every single code means but this is my first project and I'm not familiar with how different div styles work with each other due to my lack of practical experience.

Comment: @ricster which white space are you talking about?